# Maximise the function subject to constraint

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, economics

So I basically need to find

$$\max \ \left\{u(x) = \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^\rho\right)^{1/\rho}\right\}$$ subject to $p_1x_1 + p_2x_2 + \dots + p_nx_n = W$

Can I still use Lagrangian? And how should I consider boundary cases here when some of the $x$'s are zero? I want to find Marshallian and Hicksian demand functions.

Comment: what about $p,p_1,p_2,...,p_n$, are they positive or what ? what about the domain of the function $u$

Comment: @Physor , yes they are positive, nothing said about domain though and if p is greater or smaller than 1

Comment: Use duals norm  $\max p^Tx$ over $||x||_n \leq a$ is given by $a||p||_{n^*}$, should be applicable backwards.

Comment: @LeslieMay I don´t see a problem to use the Langrangian. I´ve made a numerical example which give me the right result.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [CES utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_elasticity_of_substitution#CES_utility_function) function, and you should be able to set up the first order conditions to obtain the Marshallian demand:

$$X_i({\bf p};W)=\frac{p_i^{1/(\rho-1)}}{\sum_{j=1}^n p_j^{\rho/(\rho-1)}}W$$

(you can check [here](http://www.yorku.ca/bucovets/5010/consumer/s04.pdf) if stuck). You can likewise obtain [Hicksian](http://www.yorku.ca/bucovets/5010/consumer/s06.pdf) demand by optimization. But since you have already obtained Marshallian demand, you could just use duality:

Indirect utiltiy: $$V({\bf p};W)=u(X({\bf p};W))=\frac{1}{n^{1/\rho}}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n p_j^{\rho/(\rho-1)}\right)^{1/\rho-1 }W$$

Expenditure function:

$$u=V({\bf p};e(p,u))\implies 
e({\bf p};u)={n^{1/\rho}}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n p_j^{\rho/(\rho-1)}\right)^{1-1/\rho }u$$

Hicksian demand:

$$X_i^h({\bf p}; u)=\partial_{p_i} e({\bf p};u)={n^{1/\rho}}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n p_j^{\rho/(\rho-1)}\right)^{-1/\rho }p_i^{1/(\rho-1)}u.$$